# Reducer use axios to send a request return reponse object failed

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

```js
const requestUserInfo = (state = {}, action) => {
 switch(action.type) {
  case 'HEADER_GET_USERINFO':
   axios.post('/user/getScores', qs.stringify({
    token: token,
    uid: uid
   }))
   .then(res => {
    if(res.data.status !== 200) {
     message.error(res.data.message)
     return state
    }

    return { ...res.data.attachment, ...state }
   })
   break
  default :
   return state
 }
}
// error
Uncaught Error: Given action "HEADER_GET_USERINFO", reducer "requestUserInfo" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid side effects inside your reducers!

As mentioned in the official Redux tutorial:

> Things you should never do inside a reducer:
>
> 1. Mutate its arguments
> 2. **Perform side effects like API calls and routing transitions**
> 3. Call non-pure functions, e.g. Date.now() or Math.random().

You should use [Async actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) instead, which will execute the API call, and at least possibly dispatch an action that should handle the incoming data.